# Change Content padding from top when entering text in TextFormField Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to put some padding from top, label is coming out from Textfield when entering text in TextFormField,
I tried content padding , but still not working.

[image]

here is my code

```
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) => TextFormField(
  controller: TextEditingController(),
  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle2,
  decoration: InputDecoration(
      fillColor: Theme.of(context).disabledColor,
      border: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderSide:
              BorderSide.none,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(BorderSize.input),


      ),
      contentPadding:
          EdgeInsets.all( PaddingSize.inputHorizontal),
      filled: true,
      isDense: true,
      labelText: hint),
  onSaved: onSaved,
  validator: _exists);
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be a problem with the border. If you don't need them, just remove and try.

```
      TextFormField(
      controller: TextEditingController(),
      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle2,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
          fillColor: Theme.of(context).disabledColor,
          border: InputBorder.none,
          focusedBorder: InputBorder.none,
          enabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
          errorBorder: InputBorder.none,
          disabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
          contentPadding:
              EdgeInsets.all( PaddingSize.inputHorizontal),
          filled: true,
          isDense: true,
          labelText: hint),
      onSaved: onSaved,
      validator: _exists);
```

Let me know if this is expected.

**EDIT** : 
Disable all the borders as above.

Comment: by default it is adding underline, i don't want underline.